# Dynamic input field with jquery ui slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a dynamic input field with jquery up slider but the slider works only for the first field but does not for dynamic field. here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/hpbL28ax/)

[image]

```js
$(window).load(function(){

$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              values: [ 0],
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#tasks_status" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
              }
            });

            $("#tasks_status").change(function() {
                $("#slider-range").slider('values',0,$(this).val());
            });      
            
            //Create dynamic form
       var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
        i++;  
        $('#dynamic_field')
        .append 
        ('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td width="50%"><input type="text" id="tasks_name" name="tasks_name[]" placeholder="Enter task Name" class="form-control" required/></td><td width="30%"><div id="slider-range"></div></td><td width="15%"><input type="text" id="tasks_status" name="tasks_status[]" placeholder="0" class="form-control" required/></td><td width="5%"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });







});
```

```css
.container{
  margin-top:60px;
  
}
.table td, .table th {
    padding: .1rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="name">Project Tasks</label>
     <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="table-responsive">  
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
      <tr>  
       <td width="50%"><input type="text" id="tasks_name" name="tasks_name[]" placeholder="Enter task Name" class="form-control" required/></td> 
       <td width="30%"><div id="slider-range"></div></td> 
       <td width="15%"><input type="text" id="tasks_status" name="tasks_status[]" placeholder="0" class="form-control" required/></td>  
       <td width="5%"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add</button></td>  
      </tr>  
     </table>  
     
    </div> 

     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: don't use same id for multiple time. Replace `slider-range` with class instead of id and same in html as well as append code. Also, you need to apply slider on every newly created element, hence call same function after appending new row.

**NOTE** - Replace all duplicate ids with class name or dynamic id

```js
$(window).load(function(){

    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              values: [ 0],
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#tasks_status" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
        }
     });

     $(document).on("change","input[id^=tasks_status]", function() {
          var $parent = $(this).closest('tr');
          $parent.find("div[id^=slider-range]").slider('values',0,$(this).val());
     });      
            
     //Create dynamic form
   var i=1;  
   $('#add').click(function(){  
    i++;  
    $('#dynamic_field')
      .append 
     ('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td width="50%"><input type="text" id="tasks_name" name="tasks_name[]" placeholder="Enter task Name" class="form-control" required/></td><td width="30%"><div id="slider-range' + i +'"></div></td><td width="15%"><input type="text" id="tasks_status' + i +'" name="tasks_status[]" placeholder="0" class="form-control" required/></td><td width="5%"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>'); 
            var sliderId = "#slider-range" + i;
            var statusId = "#tasks_status" + i;
            $(sliderId).slider({
                      min: 0,
                      max: 100,
                      values: [ 0],
                     slide: function( event, ui ) {
                       $(statusId).val( ui.values[0] );
             }
            }); 
          });  
 
       $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
     var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
     $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });
});
```

```css
.container{
  margin-top:60px;
  
}
.table td, .table th {
    padding: .1rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="name">Project Tasks</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
  <div class="table-responsive">  
   <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
    <tr>  
     <td width="50%"><input type="text" id="tasks_name" name="tasks_name[]" placeholder="Enter task Name" class="form-control" required/></td> 
     <td width="30%"><div id="slider-range"></div></td> 
     <td width="15%"><input type="text" id="tasks_status" name="tasks_status[]" placeholder="0" class="form-control" required/></td>  
      <td width="5%"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add</button></td>  
  </tr>  
 </table>  
</div> 
</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when change the slider only change the field other is not working. For example  if i move second slider it change the value on first input field

Comment: This is because of duplicate id `task_status`, i have updated my code to put it dynamically by using `i`. Please check the updated code now

Comment: Happy to help you. I have updated my post to handle everything by id only by generating unique id with variable `i`